# Prove that $f(v_1, v_2)$ is greater 0 $\forall v_1, v_2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the function $f_{a, b, c}\colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, $f_{a, b, c}(v_1, v_2) = av_1^2 + 2bv_1v_2 + cv_2^2$. I want to know for which $a$, $b$ and $c$ this function

- $f_{a, b, c}(v_1, v_2) > 0, \forall v_1, v_2 \in R$
- $f_{a, b, c}(v_1, v_2) \ge 0, \forall v_1, v_2 \in R$
- $f_{a, b, c}(v_1, v_2) < 0, \forall v_1, v_2 \in R$
- $f_{a, b, c}(v_1, v_2) \le 0, \forall v_1, v_2 \in R$
- None of the above.

Is there an easier method than calculating the maxima and minima of this function, and comparing those to zero?

Comment: i think in your function $f_{a,b,c}$ is a typo

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: use linear algebra, and remark that
$$
f(v_1,v_2)=\langle Av_1,v_2 \rangle,
$$
where
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
a &b \\
b &c
\end{pmatrix}
$$
You should understand when $A$ is a positive definite, or positive negative symmetric matrix. You can use standard tricks like computing the determinant and comparing its sign to that of $a$.

Comment: seeing this it is pretty clear now.